# Dialogflow to Firestore using Inline Fulfillment - Store all user data in one document

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

How do we store all user input data in one document per one chat session?

I tried this code:

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug';

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });

    function getAge(agent) {
        let age = agent.parameters.age;
        db.collection("users").add({age: age});
    }

    function getLocation(agent) {
        let location = agent.parameters.location;
        db.collection("users").add({location: location});
    }

    function getCustomerExperience(agent) {
        let customerExperience = agent.query;
        db.collection("users").add({customerExperience: customerExperience});
    }
  
    let intentMap = new Map();
    intentMap.set('age', age);
    intentMap.set('location', getLocation);
    intentMap.set('customer-experience', getCustomerExperience);
    agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

but the data were stored in different document IDs:

[image: Data stored in different IDs]

What I'm trying to achieve is something like this:

[image: Data stored in the same ID]

If I'm not being clear, please let me know. I'm new to Dialogflow, Firebase, as well as the JS language. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track! The fundamental problem with your original code is that `collection.add()` will *create a new document*. But you want it to create a new document sometimes, and save it in a previous document other times.

This means that, during the entire Dialogflow session, you'll need some way to know what the document name is or should be. There are a few possible ways to do this.

**Use a document based on the session**

Dialogflow provides a session identifier that you can get as part of the `agent.session` property using the dialogflow-fulfillment library, or in the `session` property if you're parsing the [JSON request body](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.v2#webhookrequest) directly.

However, this string includes forward slash `/` characters, which should be [avoided](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/best-practices#document_ids) in document names. Fortunately, the format of this string is [documented](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.v2#webhookrequest) to be one of the two formats:

- projects/***Project ID***/agent/sessions/***Session ID***
- projects/***Project ID***/agent/environments/***Environment ID***/users/***User ID***/sessions/***Session ID***

In each case, the *Session ID* is the last portion of this path, so you can probably use code something like this to get the ID for the session, use it as your document name, and then save an attribute (for example, age) for it:

```
  function documentRef( agent ){
    const elements = agent.session.split('/');
    const lastElement = elements[elements.length - 1];
    return db.collection('users').doc(lastElement);
  }

  async function getCourier(agent) {
    const ref = documentRef( agent );
    const age = agent.parameters.age;
    return await ref.update({age: age});
  }
```

Note that I have also made `getCourier()` an async function, because the function calls that change the database (such as `ref.update()`) are async functions and Dialogflow requires you to either make it an async function or explicitly return a Promise. If you wish to return a Promise instead, this would be something more like this:

```
  function getCourier(agent) {
    const ref = documentRef( agent );
    const age = agent.parameters.age;
    return ref.update({age: age});
  }
```

**Use the document name generated by Firestore**

With this method, you'll store a document name as a Context parameter. When you go to save a value, you'll check if this document name is set. If it is, you'll do an `update()` using this document name. If not, you'll do an `add()`, get the document name, and save it in the Context parameter.

It might look something like this (untested), again for the age:

```
  async function getCourier( agent ){
    const ref = db.collection('users');
    const age = agent.parameters.age;

    const docContext = agent.context.get('doc');
    if( !docContext ){
      // We don't previously have a document, so create it
      const res = await ref.add({age:age});
      // And set a long-lasting context with a "name" parameter
      // containing the document id
      agent.context.set( 'doc', 99, {
        'name': ref.id
      } );
      
    } else {
      // There is a context with the document name already set
      // so get the name
      const docName = docContext.parameters['name'];
      const docRef = ref.doc(docName);
      // And save the data at this location
      await docRef.update({age: age});
    }
  }
```

Again, this uses an async function. If you'd rather use a Promise, it might be something more like this:

```
  function getCourier( agent ){
    const ref = db.collection('users');
    const age = agent.parameters.age;

    const docContext = agent.context.get('doc');
    if( !docContext ){
      // We don't previously have a document, so create it
      return ref.add({age:age})
        .then( ref => {
          // And set a long-lasting context with a "name" parameter
          // containing the document id
          agent.context.set( 'doc', 99, {
            'name': ref.id
          } );
        });
      
    } else {
      // There is a context with the document name already set
      // so get the name
      const docName = docContext.parameters['name'];
      const docRef = ref.doc(docName);
      // And save the data at this location
      return docRef.update({age: age});
    }
  }
```

**Use a document name you've generated and saved in the context**

You don't need to use the session id from the first alternative. If you have some ID or name that makes sense on your own (a username or a timestamp, for example, or some combination), then you can save this in a Context parameter and use this each time as the document name. This is a combination of the first and second approaches above (but probably simpler than the second one, since you don't need to get the document name from creating the document the fist time).

Comment: Hi, @Prisoner. Thanks for helping out. I tried both methods but they aren't working because it says it's only available in ES8. I tried solving the issue with this [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/GoogleAssistantDev/comments/dv6y7t/getting_use_esversion_8_but_if_i_do_that_i_get/) but to no avail. Is there a way that I can execute this without using the async functions?

Comment: I've updated the answer to include versions without async/await, but you realy, Really, **REALLY** should upgrade to a more modern version of node.js. Versions that do not support async/await are no longer supported, and async/await make many elements of developing with node much easier.

Comment: Hi, @Prisoner. Sorry for asking again but I really tried my best to make your code work. However, Google Cloud Console's execution logs is giving me this [error](https://pastebin.com/8tPff4fZ). Do you have any idea where it went wrong? I'm using Node 10 [package.json](https://pastebin.com/zmAQi5b3). Here's my [index.js](https://pastebin.com/7UM3z4n1) for the first method.  Here's the [chatbot backup](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J_ULJxCZUtSLKG6l3ZZ0UHk7QBjcDGLw/view?usp=sharing) if you need to check it. Cheers!

Comment: This problem is unrelated to the original question, so you really should open it as a new StackOverflow question. When you do so, you should include the code, screen shots of the Intents, an example conversation that illustrates the problem, any errors you're getting, and any additional information that may be helpful.